# ¿Cómo puedo subir un fichero a la memoria del servidor sin archivo temporal en Java?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts

¿Cómo puedo subir un fichero a la memoria del servidor sin archivo temporal en Java?

Actualmente uso la librería de apache ServletFileUpload y Struts 2. Ambos crean un archivo temporal.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que necesitas hacer con dicho archivo, guardarlo en base de datos o algo similar?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza la idea es subirlo a memoria sin guardarlo físicamente en ningún sitio antes. Como si lo hicieras con sockets. En mi caso es porque no se puede tener por ley. (archivo de audio) pero podría ser por otras razones como por ejemplo servidor arrancado con memoria lenta, mayor velocidad, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la gran (pero gran) mayoría de los casos, no se justifica evitar la creación del archivo temporal. Si realmente quieres evitarlo, Struts2 no ofrece un interceptor (aunque siempre puedes programarlo). Una alternativa es usar el paquete [FileUpload de Apache Commons en modo stream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html).